# Updating portions of webpage

Tags: updating

Our web pages all have tables that are the same and periodically need updating (adding/removing products). This seems to take forever to go through each individual page that we have on our site, even with copy/paste. Is there an easy simple way to update just that portion of the page on all pages at the same time? I say easy/simple as I am a sort of neophyte, learning as I go. Kind of thrown into this position...you know cheap labor

Comment: Welcome on SO. Based on the current state of your question it is difficult to help. Are you a programmer? What technology are you using ([tag:java],[tag:c#],[tag:php] and so on), do you have static html files, do you use a [tag:cms]. Do you change the product information inside a [tag:database] and so on. Without more context it is unlikely that anyone can help.

Comment: Depending upon the way your webpage is constructed you could use things like AngularJS, for example. Your question is incredibly vague though.

Comment: We are very basic. No, I am not a programmer. As I said learn as I go. I have used some java, but only premade goodies (scrolling banner, etc) and changed those to our needs. I think at this moment I may be way over my head with my questions, sorry. But, thank you to the people that did respond.